# Way to remove javascript events from the html tags?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to remove all the javascript events from the html tags?

For example

```
<img src=" " onclick="" />
<img src=" " onerror="" />
```

I want to strip onclick and onerror from these tags. As in the example, I want to strip all the javascript events from the html tags.

Comment: not only onclick events. want to remove all the events...

Comment: Great. The backspace button works for other events too!

Comment: @ThiyagarajanSelvaraj Do you mean remove the attribute also?

Comment: Yes. I want to strip all the attributes such as onclick, ondblClick or whatever events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to clear the events :

```
// get all img elements
var imgElements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
// loop elements
for (var i = 0; i < imgelements.length; i++) { 
  // clear handler
  imgElements[i].onclick = null;
  // add other handlers here
  // imgElements[i].<here> = null;
}
```

[Docs for `getElementsByTagName()` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)

**Update 1 - All elements on document**

If you want to get all of the elements on the document then use `document.getElementsByTagName('*')`

**Update 2 - All events**

To clear all events have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6434924/572939)

Comment: he wants all HTML tags, not just the images.

Comment: @Philipp that isn't how I read the OPs question ... but anyhow I have updated the answer - `document.all` is a Microsoft thing and shouldn't be used

Comment: Microsoft explanation regarding `document.all` [is available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434(v=vs.85).aspx#CommunityContentHeader)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out jquery `.unbind()`.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

It's also easy to put the event handler back when you need it using `.bind()`

Answer (score 0):

by using jquery:

```
$('*').each(function(){      
    if ($(this).is('img')) {
        $(this).unbind('click');
    }
});
```

if you want to only remove the specific function onclick event, you can do like this..

```
 $(this).unbind('click', FunctionName);
```

As of **jQuery 1.7**, you are also able use `$.on() and $.off()` for event binding, so to unbind the click event, you would use the simpler and tidier:

```
$(this).off('click');
```

Comment: Does this really work? Can an event, specified via an attribute be canceled that way?

Answer (score -1):

Try this javascript in the document.onload event (untested):

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    all[i].onclick = undefined;
    all[i].onerror = undefined;
}
```

Comment: Event Microsoft say don't use `document.all` -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537434(v=vs.85).aspx#CommunityContentHeader

Answer (score -1):

If you mean "remove" as in physically remove them from the page source, you could probably use a regular expression to get most of them, replacing pattern `on(\w+?)="(.*?)"` with a blank string. (I've not tested, it may need tweaking)

If you mean "remove" as in logically remove them by unbinding them, you could use the unbind() method in jQuery, or set each event to null looping through the DOM.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse and manipulate HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: In a general sense, I agree completely, but if you are working with a known subset there is no reason not to. I understood the question as the OP wanted to erase javascript events from the page source. If I had to do something similar, I'm damned if I'd go through and delete manually.